# Remote control Slideshow via SOAP webservice

Tags: php, jquery, web-services, soap

I want to remote control my slideshow (jQuery plugin Cycle2) that displays pictures that are selected by the user and requested from a server via AJAX. The server side script returns the whole HTML output for the pictures and additionally a navigation bar for stopping/pausing the slideshow.

Now, what I want is to have these navigating functions as a small web app on a smartphone to remote control the slideshow run on the server. I thought about a SOAP based webservice for the interaction between smartphone and server. The problem is how do I write functions that execute actions on my slideshow? Is it possible to trigger a button of a PHP script from within a function of another one?

I hope the problem became clear. I'm not asking for code, I simply don't know how to proceed here.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, it just came to my mind. I can execute AJAX calls on the slideshow from a function of the webservice. Then however, I have to deal with these problems: [Ways to circumvent the same-origin policy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3076414/ways-to-circumvent-the-same-origin-policy)
Would that be a good way to do this?